# Is it possible to remove points or acheivements from Game Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center

Is it possible to decrease a user's points in Game Center based on something in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [GameKit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html)

```
- (void) resetAchievements
{
    // Clear all locally saved achievement objects.
    achievementsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // Clear all progress saved on Game Center
    [GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
    {
        if (error != nil)
        //handle errors
    }];
}
```

I don't think it's possible to remove scores though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by James Webster is correct, I only add the following more complete solution for future reference.

For dev I use the following in my App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
//Comment next line to prevent resetting of achievements
#define RESETACHIEVEMENTS

#if defined RESETACHIEVEMENTS
#warning RESETACHIEVEMENTS is enabled!
    // Log in to GameCentre
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) 
     {
        if (error) {
            //Handle error
        } else {
            // Reset achievements
            [GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
             {
                if (error) {
                    //Handle error
                }
             }];
        }
     }];
#endif
```